# Updating vector to avoid excess memory use

Tags: memory-management, julia

I have a function that returns an vector. Since I call this function many times, I want it to update a vector I provide to it rather than create a new vector. This is to avoid use of memory and so increase speed.

The original code essentially looks like:

```
function!(prob1,pi,prob0)
prob1=pi'*prob0
return prob1
end
```

Of course this creates a new prob1 vector each time. I've attempted to amend this in two different ways:

```
    function!(prob1,pi,prob0)
    for i in 1:length(prob1)    
    prob1[i]=pi[:,i]'*prob0
    end
    return prob1
    end

#OR

    function!(prob1,pi,prob0)
    for i in 1:length(prob1)    
    prob1[i]=dot(pi[:,i],prob0)
    end
    return prob1
    end
```

However, both run slower than the original code although they do use less memory. Any suggestions for improving performance time would be great.

Comment: are pi and prob0 column vectors? or is prob0 a matrix?

Comment: pi is a square matrix and prob0 is a column vector, making prob1 a column vector too. For the sake of example say pi is a m*m and prob0 is m*1 (so prob1 is m*1 too)

Comment: You could try devectorizing pi[:.i]... That will imply doing a nested loop... I'm not sure if that's what you need... but I think it could work for you.

Comment: There must be some typo here, because `matrix[:.i]` is not valid syntax.

Comment: Oh, you are right Tim, I thought the dot was a comma for some reason.

Comment: It was supposed to be a comma. Now corrected. I am taking the dot product of the ith column of matrix pi and prob0.

Answer (score 3):

You actually don't need to define a function, there already is one (albeit undocumented): `At_mul_B!(prob1,pi,prob0)` should give you what you want.

Comment: Hi Simon, my function is doing more than just multiplying vectors/matrices e.g. there's actually a significant amount of code after prob1=pi'*prob0. However, I would like to avoid creating a new vector at this step. How would you propose using At_mul_B! ?

Comment: He typed out explicitly how to use it, so I'm not sure I understand your question. If you have other computations, you can access the elements of `prob1`, `pi`, and `prob0` in your later code.

Comment: Yes, my apologies - I misunderstood Simon's reply. I've now tried Simon's suggestion. It does indeed significantly reduce memory use (by about a third) but still I don't get a significant reduction in speed. However, definitely worth knowing so thanks for the suggestions!